# What's the difference between `?` and `Debug.Print` in VB.Net immediate window?

Tags: vb.net, smo

Can anyone explain the following immediate window behavior:

```
Debug.Print mDb.DatabaseOptions
Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.

Debug.Print(mDb.DatabaseOptions)
Value of type 'DatabaseOptions' cannot be converted to 'String'.

? mDb.DatabaseOptions
{Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseOptions}
    AnsiNullDefault: False
    ...
    UserData: Nothing
```

According to [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode_31fbf864-1805-44ee-a586-155134905236)

> The question mark (?) is an alias for `Debug.Print`

This is clearly not 100% true, as the two statements exhibit differing behaviors in the example above.  If it makes any difference, I am using the Express Edition of VB 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the Debug.Print **method** and the Debug.Print **command**.

Commands are usually inputted in the Command.Window. To input commands in the Immediate window you need to append > before the command name so:

```
?mDb.DatabaseOptions
```

is an alias for the command:

```
>Debug.Print mDb.DatabaseOptions
```

not an alias for calling the method:

```
Debug.Print(mDb.DatabaseOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

And how do we make the "Method" behave like the command?
I have a variable like

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>> results
```

Debug.Print(results) returns

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Tuple`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]
```

...while

```
?results
    [0]: {[stringKey, (stringT1, stringT2, stringT3, stringT4)]}
    [1]: {[stringKey, (stringT1, stringT2, stringT3, stringT4)]}
    ...
```

Has I obviously wanted!